# If syntax in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to make this work in a windows batch file:

```
if not exist "%~n1.ext" (
    set /P z="PROMPT (y,n)?"
            if /i "%z%" == "y" (
                echo if is working
            )
)
```

But no matter what the input is, it never goes into the echo part. Is there something wrong in the syntax?

Comment: There's definitely something screwy - if I run it multiple times and give replies to the prompt of `a`, `b`, `c`, etc then the first time %z% is empty and after that it has the previous answer instead of the one I've just given.

Comment: another one fell into the "delayed expansion trap" ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a variable inside a block (between `(`and `)`, you need to enable delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var=hello
if "a"=="a" (
  set var=world
  echo %var% !var!
)
```

Comment: Oh I see now. I have to read about the delayed expansion then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Stephan is correct, you need to use enabledlayedexpansion when using a nested variable.  Here's your code with that syntax (replacing `%` with `!` when using such variables):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if not exist "%~n1.ext" (
    set /P z="PROMPT (y,n)?"

    if /i "!z!" == "y" (
        echo if is working
    )
)
```