# Create a file based on last modified date of another file using windows batch script

Tags: date, batch-file

I have a directory with files of kind *.aaa that I want to convert to kind *.bbb (using the exact same file name, only the file format changes) with a batch script in Windows command prompt.

Since there are many files in the directory, I don't want to do unnecessary conversion, so it should only be done if file.bbb does not exist, or if file.aaa is newer than the current file.bbb

I am quite a beginner when using batch scripts, but after doing some searching on how to compare the time that files were modified, I came up with the following `my_convert.bat` file:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.aaa) DO (
    REM Check if *.bbb already exists
    IF EXIST "%%~ni.bbb" (
        REM if *.bbb already exists, check if it is up to date
        FOR /f %%j IN ('dir "%%~ni.*" /b/a-d/od/t') DO SET LATEST=%%j
        ECHO The most recently modified file is %LATEST%
        IF %LATEST:~-3% == "aaa" (
            REM *.bbb is out of date, do my conversion here
        )
    ) ELSE (
        REM *.bbb does not exist, do my conversion here
    )
)
```

However, this does not work. It loops through all the files in my directory, but always displays that the last file in the directory is the 'most recently modified file'. I am clearly not understanding something about my implemented logic right. Any help to steer me in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23849429/2152082 (use delayed expansion)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Stephan. I've looked at the link you suggested, and then updated my procedure above as follows: inserted `code`(SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion) at the start of my program, then defined `code`(SET BASENAME=%%~ni) as the first statement in the outer `code`(FOR) loop and then replaced all subsequent `code`(%%~ni) with `code`(!BASENAME!). And this seems to have solved my problem!

Comment: And also, in all references to `LATEST` after setting its value I replaced `%` with `!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jbdv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3967096/jbdv), I summarize your comments into an answer mainly to get this question from list of unanswered questions, but adding also some additional information about difference between environment variables and `FOR` variables.

The final working code used is:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%i IN (*.aaa) DO (
    REM Check if *.bbb already exists
    SET BASENAME=%%~ni
    IF EXIST "!BASENAME!.bbb" (
        REM if *.bbb already exists, check if it is up to date
        FOR /f %%j IN ('dir "!BASENAME!.*" /B /A-D /OD /T') DO SET LATEST=%%j
        ECHO The most recently modified file is !LATEST!
        IF !LATEST:~-3! == "aaa" (
            REM *.bbb is out of date, do my conversion here
        )
    ) ELSE (
        REM *.bbb does not exist, do my conversion here
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Well, the replacement of `%%~ni` by environment variable `BASENAME` would not be necessary as code below demonstrates.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%i IN (*.aaa) DO (
    REM Check if *.bbb already exists
    IF EXIST "%%~ni.bbb" (
        REM if *.bbb already exists, check if it is up to date
        FOR /f %%j IN ('dir "%%~ni.*" /B /A-D /OD /T') DO SET LATEST=%%j
        ECHO The most recently modified file is !LATEST!
        IF !LATEST:~-3! == "aaa" (
            REM *.bbb is out of date, do my conversion here
        )
    ) ELSE (
        REM *.bbb does not exist, do my conversion here
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

The `FOR` variables `i` and `j` are **not** environment variables. Therefore `%%i` and `%%j` with or without a modifier like `~n` are never replaced by a string on parsing a block before execution.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d *.aaa '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (
   'dir /b /od /a-d "%%~na.aaa" "%%~na.bbb"'
  ) DO SET "convert=%%~xb"
 IF /i "!convert!" NEQ ".bbb" ECHO(CONVERT "%%~na"
)

POPD 

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

With each `.aaa` file, list the `.aaa` (which must exist - we've just checked that) and the `.bbb` file for the name part `%%~na` in date-order (/od) so that the last extension in the list will be `.bbb` only if it both exists and is later than the `.aaa` file. Otherwise, do the conversion - the convert command and file name will be shown on the console. You could convert `"%%~na.aaa"` if you need the full name.