# Why %errorlevel% return 0, even the psftp returns an Access Denied or Error Occurred while processing

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to run the psftp using batch file but if there's an error in psftp it always return errorlevel 0.

```
@ECHO off
ECHO Executing as user: %USERNAME%

cd "D:\program files\"

D:

SET error_level=0

psftp command....

SET error_level=%errorlevel%
```

Comment: Most likely because `psftp` returns an exit code of 0, even if it output an error.

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved my issues. When I place the psftp command inside of If condition the errorlevel doesn't recognize it. (I don't know why either)... So what I did was I created a GOTO statement instead.

Inside of my If condition I placed the GOTO statement there and call the psftp command.

```
@Echo Off
If Exist C:\Program ( GOTO DOPROCESS )

:DOPROCESS
psftp command----
```

Comment: Then you fell into the famous "delayed expansion trap". See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23849429/2152082

Comment: The reason why you didn't get the answer is because your example doesn't use loops/parentheses.  Dozens of people that respond here could have helped you if you had shown actual code.  Just a tip for the future.